# How to apply conditions on return values in Neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query as follows which returns account holder with their monthly average transaction amount.

```
MATCH (mt:MoneyTransfer)<-[s:SEND]-(:BankAccount)<-[hba:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(ah:AccountHolder)
WHERE (mt.TransactionDate <= date("2023-09-30") AND mt.TransactionDate >= date("2023-09-01"))
RETURN ah.Name as AccountHolder, AVG(mt.MoneyTransferAmount);
```

How to apply condition on above output so that I will get account holders whose average monthly money transfer amount (`AVG(mt.MoneyTransferAmount)`) is greater or less than any certain amount?

I tried multiple things but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
MATCH (mt:MoneyTransfer)<-[s:SEND]-(:BankAccount)<-[hba:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(ah:AccountHolder) 
WHERE (mt.TransactionDate <= date("2023-09-30") 
AND mt.TransactionDate >= date("2023-09-01")) 
with ah.Name as AccountHolder, AVG(mt.MoneyTransferAmount) as avgTransfer 
where avgTransfer > 1000
RETURN AccountHolder, avgTransfer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return a list of the names of the account holders that met a threshold transfer amount, and another list of the ones who did not.

```
MATCH (mt:MoneyTransfer)<-[:SEND]-(:BankAccount)<-[:HAS_BANKACCOUNT]-(ah:AccountHolder)
WHERE date($start) <= mt.TransactionDate <= date($end)
WITH ah.Name as accountHolder, AVG(mt.MoneyTransferAmount) AS avgTransfer
RETURN avgTransfer >= $amount AS metThresholdAmount, COLLECT(accountHolder) AS accountHolders
```

The query assumes that the string `start` and `end` dates, and the threshold `amount` are passed as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

For example, if there are 2 account holders, the result would look something like this:

```
╒══════════════════╤══════════════╕
│metThresholdAmount│accountHolders│
╞══════════════════╪══════════════╡
│true              │["Fred"]      │
├──────────────────┼──────────────┤
│false             │["Wilma"]     │
└──────────────────┴──────────────┘
```